# select html with native javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to toggle a class to the html tag element. I've made it work with the body element but I cannot find the solution to also toggle a class to the html tag.

```
document.querySelector('[data-menu-mobile]').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-main-mobile-open');
    document.html.classList.toggle('html-color-fill');
});
```

I know this seems to be wrong:

```
document.html.classList.toggle('html-color-fill');
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: There is not document.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `document.html` object, to get to the root element you should use `document.documentElement`.

`document.documentElement.classList.toggle('html-color-fill')`

Comment: This is not html object because the document begins from the html tag downwards? For what reason is this? Just to understand better this answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use the DOM API with more than HTML documents (for example XML or SVG) which may have the root element named differently. `document.documentElement` is markup language-agnostic way to get the root element, while `document.body` is a HTML-specific addition to the DOM API.

Comment: everything clear except language-agnostic, what do you mean with that?

Comment: `document.html` would be language-specific like `document.body` and would work only with HTML. `document.documentElement` is language-agnostic in the sense that it doesn't assume the name of the root element but will get it in whatever markup language that works with DOM API.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");

//iterate through all found elements
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
   element.className = "html-color-fill";
   //or remove class with:
   //element.className = "";
});
```

Comment: `classList.add()`, `.remove()` and `.toggle()` are the solution in modern browsers, the question was how to get the `html` element.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I did not see any sense for setting class of html element.

Comment: @pawel my project requires IE9+ and other modern browsers. So I think this will work perfectly, I'm just practising to not use jquery.